# Why is Vedanta called so and what is its relationship with Upanishads?

Tags: vedanta, upanishads

I know that the word Vendanta has two parts 'Veda' and 'Anta'. Anta means end. I have read that Vedanta is nothing but Updanishads. I have seen people using the term Veda and Vedanta as if they are same. Please can someone clarify why Upanishands are called Vendanta (If so!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vedanta means end of the Vedas, it is the cumulation of the Vedas. The Upanishads which teach the Vedanta are spread throughout different parts of different Vedas. Lord Sri Rama says in the Muktika Upanishad (Adhyaya I):

> O Hanuman, listen to Me. I shall truly describe to you the nature of the Vedanta. The Vedas were generated manifold through the exhalation of my breath as Vishnu. Like the oil in sesamum seed, Vedanta is latent in the Vedas.

and later:

> Of this there is no doubt. O son of Vayu, these 108 Upanishads, which are the essence of all Upanishads and are capable of destroying all sins through their mere study, have been imparted by Me to you as a disciple. This science of the 108 Upanishads taught by Me, is an occult one and will free persons from bondage, whether they read them with or without knowledge.

Comment: "it is the cumulation of the Vedas" - did you mean culmination instead of cumulation?

Answer (score 1):

Vedas or Sruti basically consists of two parts- karma-khanda about rituals and Jnana-khanda about ultimate Knowledge. The upanishads which deal with Brahma-Jnana (God realization) is called the end of Vedas, because it deal with the final attainment of Moksha, where as Karmakhanda deal with Dharma and other purushartas.

End of Vedas here refer to attainment of ultimate goal of life- Moksha. Hence, Upanishads are called as end of Vedas or Vedanta. Also the philosophy and world-view based on these Upanishads are called as "Vedanta".

Answer (score 0):

- Rig, Yajur, Sama and Atharva are the four Vedas.
- A Veda is divided into four parts, namely, Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka and Upanishad.

It can be seen from the division that Upanishad forms the last part of a given Veda. Since Upanishad forms the end part of a Veda it is also called as Vedanta